# Task, Action in same dictionary or alternative architecture?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

I hope I can get this explained right on the first try:

I have a `Dictionary<int, Action> MyActions`. I have a method that looks like this:

```
int actionNumber = 0;
while (isRunning) {
    if (Phases.TryGetValue(actionNumber, out var action))
    {
        action.Invoke();
    }
    actionNumber++;   
}
```

The idea is that the methods are run after each other whenever the one before has finished. And when there is an error I have the actionNumber saved so I can return to the correct last Method and continue from there.

The Methods I put into the Dictionary were initially only simple void Methods. Now I found myself I also have to put async Methods in there cause some of them have await in their body. This means the dictionary would have to keep void Methods and async Task Methods inside them. And the while loop must have an await or else it will just continue when it runs a async Task Method.

**My Solutions:**

**Solution A:**
Make the dictionary a `Dictionary<int, Task> MyActions` and make everything a Task even if it is a simple void Method. Change the while loop to:

```
    int actionNumber = 0;
while (isRunning) {
    if (Phases.TryGetValue(actionNumber, out var task))
    {
        Task.Run(() => task).Wait();
    }
    actionNumber++;   
}
```

**Solution B:**
Keep everything as it is. Wrap the async Task Methods into another void Method which itself awaits the Task Method. Put this void Method inside the action dictionary.

**Solution C:**
Turn every async Task Method into void Method and rewrite await to .Result.

---

Any other better solutions? I tend to go with Solution A because it is easier for other developers to look at the Dictionary and clearly see it all has to be Tasks.

Comment: Don't simply use .Result unless you know exactly what you're doing. Async is more involved than it may appear at first glance. Async void methods are also very specific to events and shouldn't be used in other cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `Dictionary<int, Func<Task>>`?
You can add all async methods there and await them while they are executed. If you want to add a non-async method returning void simply wrap it with:

```
Func<Task> wrapper = () => {
   simpleSyncMethod();
   return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: I will try that. I want to make it as easy as possible for the other devs to understand what to put into the dictionary and why it is this way.

Comment: How do I unwrap the Func<Task>? Do i have to first invoke and then .Wait()?

Comment: You either call: `await wrapper();` or `wrapper().Wait()`